# Wpf XmlDataProvider Validation based on XSD schema

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, validation, xamlreader

I am writing a c# (3.5 or 4 if I find a reason for it) WPF application which loads XAML fragments on the fly using XamlReader to display a customisable UI. This UI is bound to a XmlDataProvider prior to being shown and seems to work just great.

I have been trying to find out if it is possible to have the data source (the XmlDataProvider which points to a XML document) automatically validate against the document's XSD schema's?

To clarify - I am trying to avoid writing any custom validation rules because of the changable nature of the application. The XSD schema's have restrictions (such as regular expressions or max length constraints) specified which I would like my UI to respond to in a similar way as a Winforms error provider would.

Any help would be appreciated!

(Incidently - would have tagged with XmlDataProvider but cannot create a new tag due to reputation req's)

Comment: **(3.5 or 4 if I find a reason for it)** [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb613588(v=vs.100).aspx) are a couple of interesting reasons to use WPF 4.0 instead of 3.5...

Comment: @HighCore Thanks for the linky :) but I really am already sold on the benefits of a later version of .NET! The reason I'm trying to stay with v3.5 is that the users of the application generally do not have .NET 4 runtimes on their workstation and it's going to be an admin nightmare convincing the powers that be that the newer runtimes are a good thing. Office politics and devs just don't mix...

Comment: [WPF 3.5 has a really bad blurry text problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/30a818cb-521f-412c-bc11-310d35832594/). This may help you convince them.

Answer (score 3):

I worked with similar problem: loading XAML on the fly and validating user input.
But in my situation I have a global `DataContext` and all loading controls are bind to that context.
When execute validation action, for example user put button "validate" data, `DataContext` serialized to XML and after that I used XSLT for getting error tags from this XML, but I think you can use XSD if you can serialize `DataContext` for that XSD.

My steps:

1. Loading Xaml and setting my object to container `DataContext`

   ```
   String xaml="some xaml";
   MyData myData=new MyData();
   TextReader textReader = new StringReader(CardContext.Xaml);
   XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader);
   //setting DataContext for panel named 'content'
   this.content.DataContext = myData;
   FrameworkElement myContent = (FrameworkElement) XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
   this.content.Children.Clear();
   this.content.Children.Add(myContent);
   InitMyComponents(this.content);
   ```
2. Controls inside xaml bind to DataContext.
   DataContext is class MyData Like that:

   ```
   public class MyData
   {
       IDictionary<String, MyControl> MyControls{get;set;}
       ....
   }
   ```

   Where

   ```
   class MyControl
   {
      String Id{get;set;}
      String Name{get;set;}
      String Value{get;set;}
   }
   ```

   Getting binding for controls

   ```
   public static  Binding GetValueBinding(MyControl control)
   {
      Binding valueBinding = new Binding();
      valueBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
      valueBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("MyControls["+control.Id+"].Value");
      return valueBinding;
   }
   ```
3. User working with controls and changing some values.
4. When user need validation I put data in XSD schema named MyMetaData (inside that scheme I have table MyControls).

   ```
   MyMetaData _myMetaData;

   public void PushData(MyData myData)
       {

           foreach (MyControl control in myData.MyControls)
           {
            //fill table from xsd schema
      this._myMetaData.MyControls.AddMyControlsRow(control.Id,control.Name,control.Value);


           }

           this._myMetaData.AcceptChanges();
       }
   ```
5. Getting XML from DataTable

   ```
   this._myMetaData.MyControls.GetXml()
   ```
6. Validating XML using xslt

   ```
   XslCompiledTransform xslCompiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform(); 
   String xml = "some xml";
   TextReader textReader = new StringReader(xml );
   XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader);
   StringBuilder validationResult = new StringBuilder();
   XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(validationResult);
   //aply xslt (xslt return tags with error description and control Id)
   xslCompiledTransform.Transform(xmlReader, xmlWriter);
   //parsing result tags
   IList<ValidationError> parsedResult = ParseValidationResult(validationResult.ToString());
   ```
7. Finding controls and execute method for show error info

   ```
   DependencyObject errorSource = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(this.content, error.Identifier);
   if (errorSource == null)
       return;
   if (errorSource is MyControl)
      (errorSource as MyControl).ShowErrorInfo(error.ErrorText);
   ```

This is my algorithm, but if you have some constraints on XSD schema, you will get errors on step 4 when you will put data to `DataTable`.

Comment: So this is what I am doing... I have a control (say a StackPanel) defined by an XAML fragment which has a static resource which is an XMlDataProvider. When the code which loads the XAML fragment executes, it binds the XMLDataProvider to a XMLDocument by setting it's datasource. At the moment I have a seperate button which validates the XMLDocument using a SchemaSet and displaying all the errors in a message box. Are you saying that you can map these errors back to specific controls so that the validation mechanism can display the error in context of the associated control?

Comment: adding my algorithm description

Comment: Thanks for the info - this looks promising as a pointer in the right direction. I'll have to work through it at a slightly later date and will let you know if this is the answer to my problem.